# Organization Chart in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, organization-browser, organization-chart

I am new to O365 Sharepoint Online.I need to add an organisation chart to my homepage. I am trying to look into some solutions, but all solutions are 3rd party and not microsoft provided as it used to had in Sharepoint 2013 called  `Organsation Browser` in `Social Collaboration` category. Please let me know if we can add organisation chart in Sharepoint Online.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SharePoint online, there is no such feature as a web part. Here is a user voice vote about it, have a check and vote [here](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/17953939-make-the-delve-organization-chart-available-as-a-w).

For now, you can check the organization chart via the contact card. Check it [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/profile-cards-in-office-365-e80f931f-5fc4-4a59-ba6e-c1e35a85b501)

Or you can [see the chart in teams](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-organization-tab-in-teams-ff02568b-290a-46d6-ae7a-cda22f723894).

As a workaround, you can create a organizational chart via Visio. Then upload it to your SharePoint Online site and add it to your home page.

[Create an organization chart automatically from employee data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-organization-chart-automatically-from-employee-data-8f2e693e-25fc-410e-8264-9084eb0b9360)

[Display a Visio Diagram on a Web page](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/display-a-visio-diagram-on-a-web-page-cecad64e-e0c4-49d0-93e0-acdd3709c57c)